# connection to vsftp server with custom port not working

Tags: networking, ftp, port

I have setup a vsftpd server on centos 7. Service is up and running and I can connect to it via:

```
sftp user@host
user@host's password:
Connected to user@host.
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /home/user
```

I changed the listen port to 201, as a device sending data over FTP does not support sftp:

```
listen_port=201
```

I see the port changed using net netstat:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:201             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32239/vsftpd
```

But not a connection using port 201 is not possible:

```
sftp -vvvv -P 201 user@host
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xx.xx.xx.xx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 201.
debug1: connect to address 10.15.43.10 port 201: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.15.43.10 port 201: Operation timed out
```

Relevant lines in my config are:

```
listen=YES
listen_port=201
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=server
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
ls_recurse_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

What do I need to adjust in my config file? I tried several things but without success.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall ports are also open?

Comment: vsftpd is FTP server. You cannot use `sftp` to connect to it. – That does not mean that you do not have a port problem as well. You probably need to open the port 201 in your firewall.

Comment: the devices and the server are in the same subnet, there are no firewall rules in between, everything is allowed.

Comment: So did you try **FTP** client?

Comment: To make the problem a bit clearer:

Comment: I have two environments. One where a vsftpd is running on a Raspberry Pi in my home network. There I can connect to either port 22 sftp or any other port (standard 21) for ftp. I have tested this with FileZilla. On the other environment vsftpd is running on Centos7 in a different network with the identical vsftpd.conf and there I cannot connect using ftp, only sftp using port 22 is working. Network admins said there is no firewall in the subnet where the servers are. I don't understand where the problem lies.

Comment: You didn't make it clear at all. vsftpd has nothing to do with SFTP.

Comment: than it seems to be difficult to understand when something needs to uns "plain" FTP. However I solved it by installing and configuring ProFTPD as FTP Server. Files are transferred using port 21 or a custom port.

Answer (score -1):

installed and configured ProFTPD as FTP Server. That solved the problem.